# Blank spaces between .sid imges

Tags: geoserver, mrsid

I have created an ImageMosaic layer with GeoServer. In the application that uses GeoServer's WMS the layer has whitespaces at the edges of .sid as seen:

[image]

However when using GeoServer's layer preview I see that the layer is fine. 
**Update**. In layer preview I was viewing not the same layer as in first image. In layer preview was the layer that was made from .tif files (I used gdaltranslate on .sid files). So when attempting to see a layer preview (of same .sid layer as in first image) I see white image only! I am leaving second image for reference.

[image]

Note: black lines - .sid edges, blue square - area seen in first image, red - area where whitespace is

Query of a layer preview request:

```
service=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetMap&layers=X_AROUND_75_25_2_C&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:3346&bbox=575000.0,6025000.0,585000.0,6035000.0&width=768&height=768
```

Query of one of GetMap requests that browser makes:

```
SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=X_AROUND_75_25_2_C&FORMAT=image%2Fpng8&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A3346&BBOX=581202.1631283718%2C6032956.741882952%2C582556.8325043772%2C6034311.411258957&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&TRANSPARENT=true&TILED=true
```

Comment: is the WMS request in a different SRS? please add the request you made to the question using the [edit] link.

Comment: I have also updated info about layer preview as I have made a mistake